# Dropzone show files exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have a problem I am using on my website dropzone.js, but It doesnt work good for me. I have 2 problems. JSON works fine.

1. In existing files I havent remove button
2. When I upload by drag and drop it upload file twice

```
var FormDropzone = function () {

$(function() {

    var projectID = $("#projectID").html();

    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");

    $.getJSON('http://'+window.location.hostname+'/project/getFile/'+projectID, function( json ) {

      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

        var mockFile = { name: json[i].name, size: json[i].size };

        myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);

        myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "../../upload_files/project/1/"+json[i].name);

      };
    })

});

return {
    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {  

        Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
            init: function() {

                this.on("success", function(file, serverFileName) {
                  FileList = {"serverFileName" : serverFileName, "fileName" : file.name };
                });

                this.on("addedfile", function(file) {

                    // Create the remove button
                    var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement("<button class='btn btn-sm btn-block'>Remove file</button>");

                    // Capture the Dropzone instance as closure.
                    var _this = this;

                    // Listen to the click event
                    removeButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                      var projectID = $("#projectID").html();
                      // Make sure the button click doesn't submit the form:
                      e.preventDefault();
                      e.stopPropagation();
                      $.post( "http://"+window.location.hostname+"/project/deleteFile", { file_name: file.name, project_id: projectID, FileList : FileList["serverFileName"]});
                      // Remove the file preview.
                      _this.removeFile(file);
                    });

                    // Add the button to the file preview element.
                    file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
                });

            }            
        }
    }
};
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding remove button you have to add delete option i.e `addRemoveLinks : true` to the dropzone object.
just like this one :

```
Dropzone.options.mysample = {
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 1, // MB
  addRemoveLinks : true,   
};
```